# Cache in a Joomla website that have some frequently changed components

Tags: caching, joomla1.7

Some components are frequently changed (10 time/1hour), because they get data from an extern database.

For exmaple, I have a list of 5000 products. If I change the price of one pruduct, I have to refrech all cache for updating the website.

If i deactivate the cache, the website load very slowly (in 4 sec)

Do you know some extensions/trucs for resolving this :(

Thanks very much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Joomla are you using?
I know from experience that in Joomla 2.5 (and onwards) you can go to Global Configuration and change the refresh rate for the website cache in minutes.

When editing 'modules' you can also individually select the cache refresh time.

You may want to look at this Joomla Extension which provides advance caching features, it may help tackle the problem.

[Joomla Caching Extension - Click Here](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/performance/cache/13155?qh=YTo1OntpOjA7czo1OiJjYWNoZSI7aToxO3M6NzoiY2FjaGluZyI7aToyO3M6NjoiY2FjaGVkIjtpOjM7czo2OiJjYWNoZXMiO2k6NDtzOjc6IidjYWNoZSciO30=)